# I want to show Arabic text from pdf using pdfbox?

Tags: java, pdf, arabic, pdfbox

it shows letters but in reverse order of Arabic I use the following code

```
  PDDocument pddDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("test1.pdf"));
        PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();

        TextNormalize normalize = new TextNormalize("UTF-8");
        String Text = textStripper.getText(pddDocument);

      Text=normalize.makeLineLogicalOrder(Text, true);
      Text = normalize.normalizePres(Text);
      Text = normalize.normalizeDiac(Text);
        System.out.println(Text);
```

Comment: The last paragraph here http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/text_extraction.html has instructions on dealing with RTL text.

Comment: i read it but can't use ICU4J with pdfbox to show characters correctly

Answer (score 5):

The problem solved with downloading icu4j-49_1.jar from http://site.icu-project.org/download/49#TOC-ICU4J-Download putting it in class path

Then re-writing the code as follow

```
PDDocument pddDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("test1.pdf"));
            PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            String Text = textStripper.getText(pddDocument);
            System.out.println(Text);
```